# Not Escaping quotes properly while using AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

This javascript/AJAX was working on my localhost server, but when I moved it to shared hosting, it now throws an error of a called to a member function execute() on a non-object in the MySQL call.

The HTML:

```
onclick="showTrending('page_views DESC', 'product.active= &quot;y&quot; 
AND product.deleted= &quot;n&quot; ', '12', 'popular')"
```

and then the javascript:

```
function showTrending(mysql_order, mysql_limit, limit, trend)
{
$.ajax({ type: "POST", 
url: '/ajax/product_trending.php', 
data: {Mysql_Order: mysql_order, Mysql_Limit: mysql_limit, Limit: limit},
cache: false, 
success: function(result) {
 // if productSubType array is defined and has at least one element, display subcategory list
if(result != 0){...
```

and the PHP file that is called in the AJAX that is erroring out:

```
//Retrieve subcategories for supplied product type
if(isset($_POST['Mysql_Order']) && isset($_POST['Mysql_Limit']) 
&& isset($_POST['Limit'])){
$mysql_order = $_POST['Mysql_Order'];
$mysql_limit = $_POST['Mysql_Limit'];
$limit = $_POST['Limit'];
//Overlay for wishlist
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    $item_wishlist = NULL;
} else{
    $item_wishlist = $_SESSION['id'];
}
//Get product records from db
require_once($GLOBALS['domain'].'includes/connection.inc.php');
$db = dbConnect();
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();


$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT product.id, product.image_thumb, product.title,
    product.eng_title, product.price, seller.shop_name, seller.id FROM product 
    INNER JOIN seller ON product.seller_id=seller.id WHERE $mysql_limit ORDER BY
    $mysql_order LIMIT 0,$limit"); <-- This is the part that errors


$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($row['product_id'], $row['image_thumb'], $row['title'],
    $row['eng_title'], $row['price'], $row['shop_name'], $row['seller_id']);
$counter = 0;
$product_array = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()){
    ...store variables
    $counter++;
}
if($counter > 0){
    echo json_encode($product_array);
}else{
    echo json_encode(0);
}
}
```

The issue is I'm not preparing the MySQL string correctly when I insert the POST variables that are passed from the HTML.  I tested and confirmed it works if I just write the following for MySQL:

```
"SELECT product.id, product.image_thumb, product.title,
 product.eng_title, product.price, seller.shop_name, seller.id FROM product 
 INNER JOIN seller ON product.seller_id=seller.id WHERE product.active= 'y' 
AND product.deleted= 'n' ORDER BY
 page_views DESC LIMIT 0,12"
```

How should I be writing the initial HTML call correctly so I get the desired result in MySQL?

Comment: In spite of using a MySQLi prepared statement, you are getting _none_ of its benefits, and in fact your script is still vulnerable to SQL injection.  It's a bad idea to send SQL snippets in the HTTP request to build on the server side.

Comment: so just using bind_param on these snippets instead of inserting them directly in the bind_result will resolve this?

Comment: @vinsanity38 No it won't resolve it. You cannot bind arbitrary SQL snippets like `product.active= 'y'` as parameters.  It has to be bound as `product.active = ?`  And you cannot bind the `ORDER BY` column name or direction either.  You really need to rethink how the AJAX informs the PHP what should go into the SQL rather than sending SQL via AJAX>

Comment: ok, I'll remove the strings directly from the javascript and input some arbitrary numbers,  these numbers will then drive setting variables in the PHP layer for the MySQL portion so the user doesn't have access to it and I don't have to worry about escaping strings :)

Comment: Something like .. `data: {Mysql_Order: "'; drop table users; --" , Mysql_Limit: mysql_limit, Limit: limit},` should work.

Comment: @vinsanity38 That's a better plan.  Using a `switch` or something similar to translate the values from AJAX into the relevant SQL on the server side will be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hoster probably has an archaic PHP feature called `magic_quotes` enabled which causes all GET/POST/etc data to be automatically escaped. This is (a very bad) way to prevent SQL injections and it's now deprecated.

Your script has a blaring SQL injection hole and this feature is indeed "protecting" you from it. Rewrite your script so that no user input is ever added into the SQL string as-is - preferably by using parametrized queries (google it).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to bring it out to your attention that `$mysql_order` is subject to SQL-Injection.

Just because you are using prepared statement's does not mean that query is safe. 
You need to use white list for the `$mysql_order part`.

Comment: A white list, as in passing the field name and value separately and validating the field name carefully, plus using a parameter for the value (you can't parametrize a field name, but you can create a list of allowed fields and use that to validate)

Comment: That is true. In his case, he is lucky that he got an error. Many flaws like that may go undetected and that's one of the reasons why SQL Injection is still an issue after all the PDO talk as far as safety. This is an eye opener > http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4dJ7hdA8fs